# Two different XIRR errors on the same dataset

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, xirr

I attempted to calculated the XIRR from a dataset (please see the sample sheet linked below). However, on two occasions, the XIRR formula returns two different errors:

1. "XIRR attempted to compute the internal rate of return for a series of cash flows, but it was not able to."
2. "Function XIRR parameter 1 expects number values. But '' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

The errors can be found on the two respective tabs. I've checked that all $ values in the dataset are numbers and all dates are dates. Any insights into how to get the XIRR to calculate correctly is appreciated. Thank you!

[XIRR Errors](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k7mUdf1-WLgLyst6y_cBttlXCI7rxyDnSDCkPA4Cfos/edit#gid=534891516)

Answer (score 1):

*You have blank dates in Cells `B557`, `B593` [**tab_Error 2**], which I now filled with some random dates (enter valid dates OR consider disregarding them from formula calculation) as XIRR needs valid dates alongside the cashflow amounts in Column_A. its no longer throwing an error*

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, you need to use commas instead of periods in number values.
Example : -5237.63 this is wrong
-5237,63 this is true

Comment: I have changed the format according to your suggestion but the same errors persist.

Comment: You need to change the number directly, not the format, without having to try a comma instead of a period. for every cell

Comment: @EsatKurtul The syntax differences (comma, period notation) depends on the ***country locale*** settings of the sheet. For more info on this you can [check out this article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)